# Client stub for web service generation: what library to use?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, stub

What is the preferred way to generate the client stub from a WSDL file?
I tried an Axis2 plugin, it does the job.
Can WTP for eclipse generate the client stub as well?
What is a better solution?

Can you explain why you recommend such or such a way?

p.s. Does Apache CXF have Eclipse plugins for visual generation of client stub?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your favorite IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ, etc.) to do this if the Web Service is not going to be changed so much; for example, when you are trying to use a well-defined web service from another provider.

But when you are developing a Web Service of your own, you may prefer to create the WSDL from Java Code. Then you can use the tools that web service frameworks provide. For example, [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) is a great Web Service framework that provides this functionality in addition to a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WTP can generate the stup for you. Try to create a new `Web Service` project.